# how to get a java script alert when a component drag & drop from sidekick into parsys component in cq5

Tags: javascript, aem

how should I get a java script alert when a component drag & drop from sidekick into parsys component in adobe cq5.

I have the components A and B. Requirement is, component B should only draggable into component A, if the component B dragged directly into a parsys component without component A, then I should return a java script alert to the user specifying that the component B should not drag directly into parsys component.